# Не получается построить график временных рядов

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Делаю по примеру модель машинного обучения для временных рядов (модель SARIMA).
После подбора параметров для обучения модели и собственно обучения модели я начал строить график чтобы посмотреть - как хорошо модель описывает данные:

```
new_data['model'] = invboxcox(best_model.fittedvalues, lmbda)
plt.figure(figsize(20,8))
new_data.y.plot()
new_data.model[13:].plot(color='r')
plt.ylabel('LQ')
pylab.show()
```

Получаю ошибку:

---

```
NameError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-68bf2bfdf2cd> in <module>()
----> 1 new_data['model'] = invboxcox(best_model.fittedvalues, lmbda)
  2 plt.figure(figsize(20,8))
  3 new_data.y.plot()
  4 new_data.model[13:].plot(color='r')
  5 plt.ylabel('LQ')

NameError: name 'lmbda' is not defined
```

Файлы проекта доступны на файлообменнике [Проект](https://mega.nz/file/SNR0jSQJ#nOTCRr_yPQ5diG34Cpiectm4ueSfYmO2XenBOigQe_o)

Интересно, что этот же самый фрагмент кода я запускал в этом же проекте с этим же набором данных, но только с другим периодом и временным интервалом - проблем не было.
PS. Имеются ли какие-либо замечания относительно самого ряда согласно графикам?

Comment: invboxcox? Что это? Знаю inv_boxcox из https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.inv_boxcox.html

Comment: Это оно и есть. За всё кол-во попыток запустилось только один раз. Почему не запускается сейчас - не понимаю. Во всех аналогичных примерах, которые я находил - всё точь-в-точь

Comment: @passant Собственно разобрался в чём проблема, вот какая катавасия получилась :-D https://mega.nz/file/3ZIBTQKK#uuBMhMFmxXQ182cO5C3r6opFVx4Axyg-Iqrq6ZI1UQU